# Is there a way to mute just one of the Multiple Desktops in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, mute, multiple-desktop

I use the Multiple Desktops feature of Windows 10 to segregate distractions from work.

When I switch to the "Work" Desktop, I don't want any of the non-work Desktops to distract with any sounds such as when receiving a new chat in Hangouts.

So is there any way to mute just one of the Desktops when using Multiple Desktops in Windows 10?  I don't want to mute the entire PC since I put on soft music when working.

Comment: I doubt very much that this is possible, the audio subsystem is not aware of the virtual desktop feature, it handles all applications on the PC regardless of what desktop they are on.

Comment: I need more explanations: What do you mean by "mute just one of the Multiple Desktops"? How many players do you have in all the other desktop(s)? More details would help.

Answer (score 3):

do you wanna Mute All But Current Desktop?
or just mute a desktop you select by number (Desktop 1, Desktop 2, Desktop 3)?

You can do both options with this: https://github.com/FuPeiJiang/mute-virtual-desktop
Instructions in the README.md

It is in ahk, you need to install the ahk interpreter for that. https://www.autohotkey.com/
but I have compiled it for you if you don't wanna install the ahk interpreter.

so you have the choice to run "muteDesktop.ahk" or "muteDesktop_compiled.exe"
then you can use the hotkeys to do what you want:
ctrl+Numpad1 : mute desktop 1
ctrl+Numpad2 : mute desktop 2
ctrl+Numpad3 : mute desktop 3

win+Numpad1 : unmute desktop 1
win+Numpad2 : unmute desktop 2
win+Numpad3 : unmute desktop 3

win+alt+m : Mute All But Current Desktop

win+alt+u : UnmuteAll

f3 : exitApp
you can comment this line like this (to not exitApp when you press f3)
; f3::Exitapp

Update(fix): now selecting app by PID instead of exe to not confuse apps

Comment: I don't know from where you have copied this text, but the link you gave does not exist, not even in the Internet Archives.

Comment: Dude, it's super sweet of you to compile the code. It's exactly what I wanted. You deserve the bounty, here you go 

Comment: @ikolaNesla: To which software have you awarded your bounty? The link doesn't work even without the wrong anti-slash at the end.

Comment: ty TikolaNesla, I can now comment  
@harrymc, sorry, I'm new with markdown, I've replaced the \ with 2 spaces, can you try again ?

Comment: @TikolaNesla     
Update(fix) : now selecting app by PID instead of exe to not confuse apps

Comment: @Mr.Doge Just updated. Works great. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

i know a way in which you cant mute the whole desktop but you can mute any sound-creating application.here it goes-

1. Go to **Taskbar**
2. Right-click on the **Sound** option
3. Click on the **OPEN VOLUME MIXER** option
4. Mute those apps which are disturbing you!!